# What is up with the 'x' in Spy x Family?

Tags: spy-x-family

Apparently the x is not even pronounced. What's up with that? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_%C3%97_Family):

> Spy × Family (stylized as SPY×FAMILY; pronounced "Spy Family") is a Japanese manga series written and illustrated by Tatsuya Endo.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Ah thanks. There doesn't quite seem to be a confirmed answer though? Like all including the accepted answer are speculation...

Comment: Unless the author of Spy x Family has publicly stated their own reasoning behind the series title, speculation is the best you'll get. Personally I think the "stylistic choice" reason fits because the pronunciation ignores it, but "and" would also work - both of which are part of the answers.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thanks. Could this perhaps be generalised to other symbols like say + ? I can't quite think of an anime/manga(/VN/LN) with + right now though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows Hunter x Hunter. See [here](https://mangaplus.shueisha.co.jp/web_pages/263/).

> Lin: I just slapped a placeholder name on it at the draft submission stage. Endo-sensei sent in this draft for a serialization without deciding on the title, so we just worked with the title “Spy Family” written in Japanese characters for the time being. And then, when it was actually going to become a real thing, we decided we’d better have a proper name for it. It took us forever to decide on anything! (laughs) I thought “Spy Family” written in Japanese was just fine, but Endo-sensei was worried it was a little too... straight-forward. I swear, he came up with over a hundred names and we went over all of them together. And at the end of it all, we just took the name we had and put it in English characters, with a cross between the words. We talked about how the title of “HUNTER x HUNTER” is super simple, and it how it has the same thing going on.